# tornado dont accept the POST method

Tags: python, forms, mongodb, post, tornado

i get the 405: Method Not Allowed, so where is the problem, it's a 
post method since i want to send data to the server

```
class VendreHandler(BaseHandler): 
    @tornado.web.authenticated 
    def post(self): 
        self.db = conn["essog"] 
        user = self.get_secure_cookie("mechtari") 
        info = tornado.escape.json_decode(user) 
        email = info["email"] 
        namep = self.get_argument("namep") 
        prix = self.get_argument("prix") 
        description = self.get_argument("description") 
        date = datetime.datetime.now().date() 
        try: 
            photo = self.request.files['photo'][0]["body"] 
            try: 
                avctype = self.request.files['avatar'][0]["content_type"] 
                image = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(buf=avat)) 
                type = image.format 
                (x, y) = image.size 
                if x < y: 
                   orientation = "portrait" 
                else: 
                   orientation = "paysage" 
                pref = str(time.time())
                nomfi = pref.replace(".", "") 
                nomfich = nomfi + "-" + self.request.files['avatar'][0]["filename"] 
                self.fs = GridFS(self.db) 
                avatar_id = self.fs.put(avat, content_type=avctype,filename=nomfich) 
            except IOError, TypeError: 
                self.redirect("/error-im") 
        except KeyError: 
            nomfich = "nofile" 
            orientation = "paysage" 
            avctype = "image/jpeg" 
            avatar_id = '503ae8553a5f3a0dd8b9cb4c' 
    self.db.users.update({"email":email}, {"$set":{"produit_up.namep":namep,"produit_up.prix":prix,"produit_up.photo":photo_id, "produit_up.description":description,"produit_up.date":date, "produit_up.vendu":False}}) 
    self.redirect("/success")
```

and the template:

```
<form id="formvente" name="formvente"  method="post" action="/vendre" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
{% raw xsrf_form_html() %} 
<label for="namep">Le nom du Produit</label> 
<input type="text" name="namep" required title="vous devez mettre le nom du produit" placeholder="exemple: peugeot 206"> 
<label for="prix">Son prix (en Dinars Alg&eacute;rien)</label> 
<input type="number" name="prix" required title="vous devez mettre le prix en chiffre (en Dinars Alg&eacute;rien)" placeholder="exemple: 800000"> 
<label for="photo">Une photo de votre produit</label> 
<input name="photo" type="file"> 
<label for="description">Veuillez donner une d&eacute;scription du produit (maximum 160 caract&egrave;res)</label> 
<textarea name="description" id="description" rows="3" cols="60" required title="vous devez mettre une petite description" placeholder="escence, 2006, roulant 100000km, toutes options, siege en cuir"                                 onKeyDown="textCounter(document.formvente.description,160)"                                        onKeyUp="textCounter(document.formvente.description, 160)"></textarea> 
<meter name="shower" min="1" max="160" value="1"id="shower" low="30" high="140">afficher son etat</meter> 
<input id="vendre" type="submit" value="Mettre en Vente"/> 
                            </form>
```

and i have simplified the handler to this

```
class VendreHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler): 
    def post(self): 
        namep = 1 
        prix = 3 
        description = 43 
        date = 345 
        self.db = conn["essog"] 
        self.db.users.update({"email":email}, {"$set":{"produit_up.namep":namep,"produit_up.prix":prix, "produit_up.photo":photo_id, "produit_up.description":description,"produit_up.date":date, "produit_up.vendu":False}}) 
        self.redirect("/profil#vendu")
```

always the method error it dident check the handler content at all 
(else it raised and error when not finding email)!

- NB: is it because i've used the accodion effect (CSS3)? the page contains 3 parts: the profile, upload product, and search for product, and of course every part has its own handler; so the profile will call 
  a GET to get the user information and the avatar, and the upload product will make a POST to write product information to the server, and finally the search will make a GET to the server to search for the product. 
  so, am i making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!
it seems that the problem is coming from the picture handler; in the URLSpec, IT MUST BE THE LAST ONE IN THE LIST

```
url = [
...,
...,
...,
(r"/(?P<picture>.*)", handlers.PictureHandler)]
```

this is why when using GET method return errors concerning picture!
hope this will help, and thank you :)

Comment: Glad you solved it, but in the future you should also include your URLSpec :-)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this solves nothing. The source of the error must be other.